# Sites built using HTML 5 Mobile Boilerplate

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, web, html5boilerplate

Which famous mobile websites use [HTML 5 Mobile Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/html5boilerplate.com/dist/mobile/) ?

Any other good alternatives except JQuery Mobile?

Answer (score 0):

There is a blog on tumblr that list some of the popular sites, built with html5 boiler plate:

http://html5boilerplate.tumblr.com/

A little trick to see if the site has been built using html5 boilerplate is to lookout for the following meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
```

Comment: "A little trick to see if the site..." - why do you think so?

Comment: I heard paul(the creator of boilerplate) once in  a talk about this.

Comment: It can be any other site who aren't made with html5 bp

Comment: Weirdly enough, this line fails W3C validation, and so I have removed it (I use another method to force IE=edge, etc.) The JS libraries included with the boilerplate fails JS validation, so I just gave up :)

Comment: -1 Please pay attention. The question asked for sites for **mobile** websites.